# Rename vector rownames

Tags: r, row, radix

Here is my replicating example.

```
data <- c(100:105)
```

As you can view the rownames are 1:6. Instead I would like to change the rownames to a column I have called "names" where

```
names <- c(0,10,20,30,40,50)
```

I tried

```
cbind(names,data)
```

but this results in rownames being 1:6, and then a column for names, and a column for data. I want to replace the rownames 1:6 with the column "names"

Desired output:

```
0   100
10  101
20  102
30  103
40  104
50  105
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
data <- data.frame(data)
row.names(data) <- names
data
```

Result:

```
   data
0   100
10  101
20  102
30  103
40  104
50  105
```

EDIT: if you want to keep a vector:

```
data <- c(100:105)
names <- c(0,10,20,30,40,50)
attr(data,'names') <- names
attributes(data)
$`names`
[1] "0"  "10" "20" "30" "40" "50"
```

Comment: That makes a data frame, how can I make a vector? @gpier